# How to rotate custom marker image on google map v3

Tags: google-maps, rotation, google-maps-markers

after 4-5 hours of googling how to rotate custom marker image on google map v3, i am posting here this question. please suggest any solution with example.

Comment: hi nobody has idea about it, please help me its really important for me.

Answer (score 2):

Code by `user1884506` is very helpful but it rotates default icon.

You cannot rotate a custom image. Reference
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Symbol

**The symbol's path, which is a built-in symbol path, or a custom path expressed using SVG path notation. Required.**

To do it you need to create image using SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics).

Answer (score 1):

**please refer the below code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function kh(i, j, k) {
    var a;
    var b;
    if (j != null && k != null) {
        a = j;
        b = k;
    }
    else {
        a = 12.9540112248064; b = 77.6991748809814;
    }
    if (i != null) {
        var angleDegrees = i;
    }
    else {
        angleDegrees = 0;
    }
    var angle = 45;


    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(a, b);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var arrowIcon = new Image();
    arrowIcon.src = "../Image/CarNew.png";
    var image = '../Image/add.jpg';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(a, b);
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_OPEN_ARROW,
scale: 2,
rotation: angleDegrees           }    

     });document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value=a;


document.getElementById("HiddenField2").value = b;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;


public partial class NewFolder1_Rotatev3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = null;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        file = new System.IO.StreamReader("D:\\GoogleMapsDemo\\Files\\closepoints.txt");
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "_ShowHideBusiJust_", "i();", true);
        Session["file"] = file;
    }
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    file = (System.IO.StreamReader)Session["file"];
    string[] strdata = null;
    line = file.ReadLine();
    if (line != null)
    {
        strdata = line.Split('\t');
        string j = strdata[0];
        string k = strdata[1];
        Session["Lat"] = j;
        Session["Long"] = k;
        int R = 6371; // km
        double lat1 =HiddenField1.Value != null ? Convert.ToDouble(HiddenField1.Value) : 0;
        double lat2 = Convert.ToDouble(j);
        double lon1 = HiddenField2.Value != null ? Convert.ToDouble(HiddenField2.Value) : 0;
        double lon2 =Convert.ToDouble(k);
        if (!(lat2 == 0 && lon2 == 0))
            {

            var dLat = DegreeToRadian((lat2 - lat1));
            var dLon = DegreeToRadian((lon2 - lon1));
            lat1 = DegreeToRadian(lat1);
            lat2 = DegreeToRadian(lat2);
            var a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Sin(dLon / 2) * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2);
            var c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
            var d = R * c;
            var y = Math.Sin(dLon) * Math.Cos(lat2);
            var x = Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Sin(lat2) -
                    Math.Sin(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2) * Math.Cos(dLon);
            var brng = (Math.Atan2(y, x));
            var last = RadianToDegree(brng);
            Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(d);
            string i = Convert.ToString(last);
            Session["Angle"] = i;
            string script = string.Format("i({0},{1},{2});",
                              i.ToString(), j.ToString(), k.ToString());
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", script, true);
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //strdata[0]   - Latitude
        //strdata[1]   - Langitude
            }

    }
    else
    {
        string i = Convert.ToString(Session["Angle"]);
        string j = Convert.ToString(Session["Lat"]);
        string k = Convert.ToString(Session["Long"]);
        string script = string.Format("i({0},{1},{2});",
                              i.ToString(), j.ToString(), k.ToString());
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "RefreshOpener", script, true);
        Timer1.Enabled = false;

    }
    Session["file"] = file;
}
 private double DegreeToRadian(double angle)
{
    return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
}
private double RadianToDegree(double angle)
{
    return angle * (180.0 / Math.PI);
}

}
```

Comment: What's this??? User asked how to rotate a marker on Google Maps V3 API for javascript, you just posted a random piece of code, without any explanation of what it does, and it isn't even written in javascript. Next time please at least properly describe and explain your answer, as this won't help anyone.